# third party tool for chat?

Tags: java, spring, chat

I want to develop a chat application for my product. Its done in java and spring .

The people in my product have there own domain name.

can you suggest any good third party tool, which is free.

Comment: Did you read through all of the other questions on this topic?

Comment: @Stephen C : i saw DWR and some other tool. I googled DWR but it doesnt give much details of how to track clients like that. Can u suggest one ?

Comment: Stop asking the same question repeatedly.  You can edit questions to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You question is very broad but you could take a look at http://java-source.net/open-source/chat-servers for Open-Source Chat Servers written in Java. But these are actual servers that run and clients connect to. As you mentioned a domain-name you might want a Web Based Chat Solution, check out - http://chipchat.sourceforge.net/ - for this.

Update Users want a Web Based solution using a Comet Approach

Maybe try - http://avricot.com/blog/index.php?post/2009/05/19/AvriChat-%3A-Real-time-Chat-Javascript-Comet-and-Java-Server or - http://cometdaily.com/2009/10/23/concrete-comet-examples/ also shows a example of chat with comment

**Please try Google it has all the information you will ever need.**

Comment: It uses applet can u suggest some one tht uses the comet technique

Comment: how about using smack API any experience in that ?

Answer (score 0):

What about XMPP (the open protocol which is used by, amongst others, GTalk)?  Have a look at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the project itself, but because it is an API to the protocol I am sure you can implement the presentation layer however you see fit.