# chat application in java?

Tags: java, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [third party tool for chat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483103/third-party-tool-for-chat)

I want to develop a chat application in java. The requirements are:

1. It should be web based and client server type.
2. I dont want to use applet .
3. I need to use my company domain. (rather than gmail or yahoo)

I want to integrate this chat with my existing product . which is developed using spring frame work.

Is there any third party tool that is free?

Comment: "web based" "dont want to use applet" - Then in what aspect is it web based java?

Comment: @Harry joy : i didnt know about smack, i just googled that i saw open Fire server ? how good smack API is, does it using comet ? how can i track the clients in SMACK API

Comment: @ Eric : cant i use JSp ? i didnt know much im a beginner

Comment: @HArry Joy : why u deleted  u r comment ?

Comment: any one having experience with claros server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an overview:
http://java-source.net/open-source/chat-servers

Comment: i tried with claros chat ? u have any experience with this ? can i integrate this with my website? does it support other domains(i want it for my company domain xyz.com)

Comment: No experience but I'm sure all this can be found out about on their side or googled...

Answer (score 0):

1- You have to install a pre developed Chat server. There is many available solutions I advice you to choose Ejabberd ( http://www.ejabberd.im/ ). It's a chat server implemented using Erlang and is considered as a highly scalable server. It's the same as facebook chat server, note that facebook used at the beginning only one server to handle all its chat traffic all over the world.

2- You have to integrate a js chat client that will communicate with the chat server. There is also a cool open source solution for that called ijab ( http://code.google.com/p/ijab/ ). You have just to configure it to connect with your server.

3- To add friends and manage interactions between users, you can use a java jabber library and there are many. This library will be used to connect to ejabberd server. You can choose one of the java clients but there are many.

You'll encounter many problems in the configuration of chat so don't under estimate it

Comment: Is ejjaberd implemented in java? Is it possible to integrate this with my existing product ? can i use my own domain name ids to chat rather than gmail or yahoo i want this to use in mycompany id only is tht posiible ? thanks in advance

Comment: i read this comment earlier. does ejjabered written in java

Comment: No actually Ejabberd is implemented in Erlang, the most scalable developeing language. There are other implementations of jabber servers but I routed you to the best and the most scalable. However, you can communicate with your server using sockets over Jabber protocol. There are many java libraries that can talk with jabber servers (EjbberD included)